# JSHint in my vim marks 'yield' as a warning.

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, jshint

I'm writing some mocha tests and using vim with JSHint.
Unfortunately JSHints gives me A LOT of warnings due to the 'yield' keyword.

> 'yield' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).

This is warning W118 and I have tried to disable this warning in my .jshintrc file with

```
{
    "mocha": true,
    "-W118": true
}
```

but so far I am unsuccesfull in hiding this warning. Any ideas why? 
I have already read the documentation and I don't want to use any inline configuration.

Comment: _an idea_ Try setting `"esversion": 6,` in the .jshintrc

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [melchor629](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938013/melchor629) for finding an answer. Setting

> "esversion": 6

in my .jshintrc file fixed the problem.